# How do I check a certain query result (MySQL) is not empty in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm  making a simple 'army' game in PHP. I'm using a database, so you can create an account, like a username and a army (name). Using the database, I can check if you have created an army, before you advance to the game. Unfortunately, I don't know how.

So this is my code:

```
<?php


include('connect.php');   //a file where I connect to my database

session_start();

//now I want to check if the person has created an army:
$query = "SELECT army FROM Account WHERE username = $_SESSION['username']";

if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query))==0) {
echo "Please create an army to continue";
}

else {
echo "Have fun playing this game";
}

?>
```

Btw: $_SESSION['username'] excists. I echooed it and it displayed the username.
I think the fault has something to do with `mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query))==0`, but I'm not sure.

> syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

This is the error my browser gives.

Now, this code doesn't work, seeing the error the browser gives. Does anyone know what I should do to achieve my goal in checking for somoene's army excistence in my database for making sure this person doesn't start a battle without an army and for making sure my browser doesn't give any error?

Thank you.

Comment: `WHERE username = $_SESSION['username']";` that's a string, treat it as one http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html - you see the error here? `expecting identifier (T_STRING)`

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements, it really isn't hard.